# Unexpected code after tree-shake

Tags: typescript, webpack, uglifyjs, dead-code, tree-shaking

Given `entry` is the entry module:

[image]

It just uses `function1` from `external1` module.

I expected that `external1.function2` and the whole `external2` module would be eliminated.

However, my output includes `external2.function1`. Just.. why?

[Here's a repo](https://github.com/Birowsky/testing-typescript-treeshaking) of the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

tree shaking is not working perfectly since javascript in nature is dynamic language, so sometimes it does pessimistic guess given code *maybe* used in other places. in external1, you've imported everything from external2 via * as xxx from 'external2' - and that makes assumption to bundler given exported module might have reference in somewhere else and does not delete it.

Comment: if that was true, we would also see `external2.function2` in the output. but it's not the case. anyhow, i updated the repo to import only the specific function through `import {function1 as f1} from './external2';`. the output is the same.