# Webpack5 does not seem to tree-shake unused exports

Tags: webpack, webpack-5, tree-shaking

I set up a small project with the following files

```
- src/
  - lib/
    - lib1.ts
      - export : func_lib1_1, func_lib1_2
    - lib2.ts
      - export : func_lib2_1, func_lib2_2
  - pkg1/
    - pkg1.ts
      - import & use : func_lib1_1, func_lib2_1
  - pkg2/
    - pkg2.ts
      - import & use : func_lib1_1
  - pkg3/
    - pkg3.ts
      - import & use : func_lib1_1
```

I configurated the various build/package/optimisation settings as per [the official documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) :

### webpack.config.js

```js
    mode: "production",
    optimization: {
        usedExports: true,
    },
```

### package.json

```json
    "sideEffects": false,
```

### pkgX.ts

```ts
    import { func_lib1_1 } from "../lib/lib1";
    
    console.log("pkgX");
    console.log(func_lib1_1());
```

But in the resuting bundles I still see the unused function func_lib1_2 and func_lib2_2 being inclued:

### pkg1.bundle.js

```js
    /***/ 119:
    /***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, exports) => {
    
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", ({ value: true }));
    exports.func_lib1_2 = exports.func_lib1_1 = void 0;
    function func_lib1_1() {
        return "func_lib1_1";
    }
    exports.func_lib1_1 = func_lib1_1;
    function func_lib1_2() {
        return "unused, shouldn't be bundled";
    }
    exports.func_lib1_2 = func_lib1_2;
    
    /***/ }),
```

Do you know why? What can I do to fix this and get the by-the-book tree-shaking that I seek?

#### [Minimal repro setup available here](https://loveteit.fr/files/tree_shaking.zip)

Thanks in advance

## Update : more infos from optimizationBailout: true

```
  modules by path ./src/lib/*.ts 666 bytes
    ./src/lib/lib1.ts 333 bytes [built] [code generated]
      Statement (ExpressionStatement) with side effects in source code at 2:0-62
      ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
    ./src/lib/lib2.ts 333 bytes [built] [code generated]
      Statement (ExpressionStatement) with side effects in source code at 2:0-62
    ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
  ./src/pkg1/pkg1.ts 263 bytes [built] [code generated]
    Statement (ExpressionStatement) with side effects in source code at 2:0-62
    ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
  ./src/pkg2/pkg2.ts 182 bytes [built] [code generated]
    Statement (ExpressionStatement) with side effects in source code at 2:0-62
    ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
  ./src/pkg3/pkg3.ts 182 bytes [built] [code generated]
    Statement (ExpressionStatement) with side effects in source code at 2:0-62
    ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
```

This is intriguing. Is there something wrong with the way I declare my exports?

## Update 2 : it works without ts-loader!

I tried changing all files to .js and removing the whole ts-loader thing. Tree-shaking now work as intented.

The updated question now is : how to make it work with typescript?

### Similar questions that may be revelant, but with different context

- [webpack 4, same situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48154266/unexpected-code-after-tree-shake?rq=1)
- [webpack 4, with a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48357363/webpack-tree-shaking-can-t-extract-unused-function?rq=1)
- [webpack 4, with import *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48599352/webpack-including-unused-exports-in-final-bundle-not-tree-shaking?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out myself, auto-answer for the record :

The tsconfig.json was wrong, it wasn't preserving the ES6 module syntaxe so webpack couldn't treeshake properly.

[More details on the correct configuration (optionally including Babel too) can be found here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org/issues/995)